# sudo permissions without root access

Tags: permissions, sudo, users

I want to give certain users on my server access to run commands as apache, but I don't want to give them full root access.

Is there a way to allow a user to run a command similar to `sudo -u apache ...` while preventing them from having root permissions?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I thought he just didn't want to give them full root access. If you really want to give them this power without `sudo` then, uh... Why?!

Comment: @ajon - hover over the downvote arrow. This is very rudimentary sudo stuff, and the downvote is likely due to the fact that you show no research effort on an issue that would have been easily sorted out with a simple web search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course, this is exactly what `sudo` is for. e.g.:

```
ajon  ALL=(apache) /bin/ls
```

Allows the user ajon to run `sudo -u apache /bin/ls`.
See `man sudoers`.